# How to avoid false variable with htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi guys im new in stackoverflow so here is my problem

i have a controller file php  and my htaccess

if have this php controller

```
if ($_GET['var1'] and $_GET['var2']){include_once('file.php')}
```

and this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /controller.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

my problem is

if i type [www.site.com/var1/var2/](http://www.site.com/var1/var2/)   this one is a real path so, is ok.
but if i type [www.site.com/var1/var2/hjwuwjais/](http://www.site.com/var1/var2/hjwuwjais/)     this url need show error 404 but still show file.php because have var1 and var2..

```
-------------real-real-non-exist--    
www.site.com/var1/var2/hjwuwjais/
```

so how i can solve it... if i type  any false or non-existent var in url show 404?

Comment: Makes no sense to me to show 404 and keep the normal path. Or you show 404 or you include the file and ignore the 3rd parameter.

Comment: You are right, but how reditect to 404 if the parameter non-exist?

Comment: The only GET parameter set in your rewriting rule is `id`. There is no "var1" and "var2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in the missing gaps in your question, maybe you should only rewrite to your *controller* when you have exactly two path segments?

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/?)$ /controller.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So, only requests of the form `/<something>/<something>/` (trailing slash optional) are routed to your *controller*. Anything else will naturall fall through to a 404 (unless it happens to map to a physical file).

This handles an optional trailing slash, although you should ideally include it or omit it from your URLs.

If you are more restrictive in your regex then you can probably avoid the filesystem checks.

Incidentally, in your original regex `^(.*)/?$`, the trailing `/?` is entirely superfluous since the capturing subpattern `.*` is *greedy*.

---

**UPDATE:**

> but if i type `www.example.com/var1/var2/hjwuwjais/` this url need show error 404 but still show `file.php` because have `var1` and `var2`.

Ah OK, that would seem to render my answer above incorrect. But also this doesn't have anything to do with `.htaccess`? And as noted in comments, doesn't really make sense. (?)

---

*Aside:*

> if have this php controller
>
> ```
> if ($_GET['var1'] and $_GET['var2']){include_once('file.php')}
> ```

I assume this is very pseudo-like code... where are `$_GET['var1']` and `$_GET['var2']` coming from? You are only passing `$_GET['id']` to `controller.php`?

Comment: Thanks a lot MrWhite i solve my issue with your code, thanks